# How to include the same element (nbr. or symbol) between the elements of a list in scheme?

Tags: aiohttp

I am getting started with the basics of scheme right now. I came across an exercise where a procedure needs to be created which adds the element *x* that can be symbols or numbers in between the elements of a given *list*.

For example:

The procedure `(tech 7 (list 23 24 25))` should result in `(23 7 24 7 25)`.

So far I have only a theoretical approach. It aims at splitting up the given list in `car` and `cdr` and to combine `cdr` with a newly created *list* of the element *x* thru `append`.

```
(define (tech x lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (car lst) (append (cons ('x) (* 'x (length cdr lst))
                                    (cdr lst)))))
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the code? It only returns errors...

Comment: The question doesn't have anything to do with trigonometry, removing the tag.

Comment: You should spend more time studying the syntax of the language, how to build a list and how to write a recursive procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- You should avoid using `append`, most of the time using `cons` is the correct approach for building a list.
- Why are you multiplying `'x` by the length of the list? that doesn't make any sense.
- You're confusing the *symbol* `'x` with the *value* of the `x` *variable*.
- You need to consider a third case for handling the last element, because the list doesn't end in `x`.
- Last but not least: you forgot to call the recursion! it'll never work if you omit a call to `tech` inside `tech`.

This fixes all the issues, most of the original code had to be rewritten:

```
(define (tech x lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())       ; base case: empty list
        ((null? (cdr lst)) lst) ; list with a single element
        (else (cons (car lst)   ; this is how we add
                    (cons x     ; the element to the list
                          (tech x (cdr lst))))))) ; advance recursion
```

It works as expected:

```
(tech 7 '(23 24 25))
=> '(23 7 24 7 25)
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, Oscar! I guess I will get back to the books then but I appreciate your effort!

Comment: My pleasure, you'll get on the right track in no time after some studying :) . Cheers!